# Creating a rectangle class w/ GUI (errors)

Tags: java, user-interface, rectangles

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't create a rectangle when I call it in my GUI class. All i would like to do is create a rectangle based on my rectangle class but i get these errors in my DataPanel class below and can't figure out why.

```
Error:(21, 5) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(21, 15) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(21, 25) java: ';' expected
Error:(21, 36) java: ';' expected
```

```
public class DrawRooms{

int x,y,width,height;

public DrawRooms() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    width = 0;
    height= 0;
}

public DrawRooms(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
}


//sets x coordinate
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

//sets y coordinate
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

//sets width
public void setWidth(int w) {
    this.width = w;
}

//sets height
public void setHeight(int h) {
    this.height = h;
}

//gets x
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

//gets y
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

//gets width
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

//gets height
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

//toString to report values
@Override
public String toString(){
    String s = "\nX-Coordinate: " + getX() +
            "\nY-Coordinate: " + getY() +
            "Width: " + getWidth() +
             "Height : " + getHeight();
    return s;
}
}

public class DataPanel extends JPanel {

public DataPanel() {
    repaint();
    buildPanel();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void buildPanel() {
    DrawRooms room = new DrawRooms(50, 100, 600, 600);

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        room.draw(g2d);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: kindly put you paint(...) out of buildPanel()

Comment: Your code is formatted wrong. You have defined the paint method within the buildPanel method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have been put paint-method into buildPanel(..){..} which is wrong
>   syntax.
>
> so carry out paint(...) from buildPanel(...)

do something likewise,

```
 DrawRooms room ;
public void buildPanel() {
    room = new DrawRooms(50, 100, 600, 600);

}

protected void paint(Graphics g) { // put this method out of buildPanel()
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    room.draw(g2d);
 }
```

Comment: By doing that i get this error Error: (33, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable room
  location: class GUI.DataPanel

Comment: 1: avoid overriding paint; 2: calling super.paintComponent from paint is a really, really bad idea; 3: your code won't compile (even assuming the class was filled out correctly)